# Is there a fix for Intel graphics driver problem and sp1 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, intel-graphics

Windows Update still hasn't given me SP1 yet and I have `igdumd64.dll` driver is there a fix yet?

Comment: what problem do you have?, and what is your graphics adapter?

Comment: A fix for what?  What is your problem?

Comment: Windows update won't display the service pack and i read a kb from microsoft explaning why but i dont know if theres a fix for it

Comment: Can you post a link to the kb?

Comment: @Matt Jenkins link:support.microsoft.com/kb/2498452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Knowledge Bulliten you shared, the problem lies with Intel. Microsoft says to check for a new driver from Intel. http://downloadcenter.intel.com/

You can run the [Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/) if you're not sure which graphics chipset you're using.

If Intel hasn't release a new driver yet, the KB kind of implies you can downgrade to a driver before version 8.15.10.2104 in order to receive the update.

Comment: How do i downgrade

Comment: If you know what type of graphics chipset you're using, and you can find the drivers preceding 8.15.10.2104, then you would download those, uninstall your current ones, and install the old ones that you downloaded.

GPU-Z can help you identify your Intel GPU if you don't know.